# How to active resizable event on each component ( one by one )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my Codepen link: [`resizable event`](https://codepen.io/shinva1205/pen/xXGdWj)

I'm using Jquery UI resizable, thing is working fine but now I want to the resizable event on each block only active one by one, if you click another block, the resizable event on the previous block will be destroy, I've tried the .each function but it's not working.

Same thing when I try to destroy the resizable event when click anywhere on the screen except the div, I got the Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a component is clicked, got resizable, you should mark it as resizable enabled by adding a class. Like:

https://codepen.io/ducfilan/pen/jGPwop

```js
$(document).on("click", ".component-items", function () {
    $('.processed-resizeable').resizable("destroy");
    $('.processed-resizeable').removeClass("processed-resizeable");
  
    $(this).resizable();
    $(this).addClass('processed-resizeable');
  
    $(this).draggable({
      start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).resizable("destroy");
      }
    });
});
```

```css
.component-list {
  border:1px solid #343434;
  margin-top:50px;
  padding:5px 20px;
  height:300px;
  position: relative;
}

.component-items {
  cursor:pointer;
  position: absolute;
}

.ui-resizable {
  border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

#items-1 {
  top:10px;
  left:500px;
}
#items-2 {
  bottom:100px;
  left:15px;
}
#items-3 {
  top:100px;
  right:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="component-list">
        <div class="component-items" id="items-1">
          <h3>Block 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component-items" id="items-2">
          <h3>Block 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component-items" id="items-3">
          <h3>Block 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for the help, it work great, and can you help me with the function when user click anywhere on the screen except the resizable div, it will destroy the resizable event ?